# chimp.js configuration - the browser is not opening localhost

Tags: testing, end-to-end, chimp.js

I am having problem with chimp.js configuration. When I run tests the browser is not using provided host / post. I tried many things but without success. Does anyone know how to set up it properly? Please find my config in screenshot provided.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser first starts, it defaults to `data;`. You need to navigate somewhere first.

The host and port settings are not related to browsing. They tell Chimp where the Selenium server is, which by default is chromedriver.

Comment: no problem. please accept this answer if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to setup beforeFeature hook to start using localhost:3000